# Jquery track changes on a drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use jquery or javascript to track changes when an input box's value is changed using a drop down box.

I gave the input box a `firechange` class and tried to use jquery `change()` event but the event does not fire at all.

Is there a way to check drop down box selection.

```js
  $('.fieldsWrapper').on('click', '.dlInput', function(e) {
    // e.stopPropagation();
    // load datalist into memory
    var dl = "";
    dl += "<div class='dlOption'>Red</div>";
    dl += "<div class='dlOption'>Yellow</div>";
    dl += "<div class='dlOption'>Green</div>";
    $(".helper").html(dl);
    loadDatalist(dl)
})


function loadDatalist(dl) {
    // $("#helper").width( $("#dlInput").width() );
    $(document).on("click", ".dlInput", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        // display list if it has value
        var lv = $(".dlInput").val();
        if (lv.length) {
            var os = $(".dlInput").offset();
            $("#orderTypes").attr("id", "orderTypesHide");
            var activeElement = $(document.activeElement)
            var helper = activeElement.next()
            $(helper).show();
            // $('#helper').show()
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".dlOption", function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).parent().prev('.dlInput').val($(this).html()); //The parent class is the helper and the class before should be the Input box of the class dlInput
        $(".helper").hide();
    });

    $(document).on("change", ".dlInput", function() {
        if ($(this).val() === "") {
            $("#orderTypesHide").attr("id", "orderTypes");
            $(".helper").hide();
        }
    });

}


$('.fireChange').change(function(){
    alert(`Input Event Fired`)
    // addIndividualParts()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="fieldsWrapper">
<input list="orderTypes" class="fireChange dlInput" class="form-control fireChange" placeholder="Stage" value="Red">
            <div class="helper"></div>
            <datalist id="orderTypes">
               <option value="Red">
               <option value="Green">
               <option value="Yellow">
            </datalist>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the new value of an element, in your case the `.dlInput` class, you need to call [trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) change jQuery method.

Here's working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r8h3dxoj/6/

So the line of your code I've changed is:

```
$(this).parent().prev('.dlInput').val($(this).html()).trigger('change');
```

Comment: This is working but the problem is that it is firing the event more than once

Comment: That is a completely separate issue, your question was on one specific issue and my answer solves that so you should accept it and post another question if you can't solve the other issue on your own. [One question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery I'm presenting below works (its functionally the same as yours). I believe it is working, but not when one might expect.

```
$('.fireChange').change(function(){
    console.log('input value changed.');
});
```

This change event listener is only going to fire once you've taken focus from the text input box. On a select dropdown the change even fires as soon as an option is selected, but since the datalist is effectively functioning as a set of auto complete options on the text input, this event feels like it happens pretty late. That might be why you aren't seeing it trigger.

Docs:
Depending on the kind of element being changed and the way the user interacts with the element, the change event fires at a different moment:

- When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not committed (e.g., after editing the value of  or ).
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Side note:

On the html front you probably only need one class attribute.

```
class="form-control fireChange dlInput"
```

Comment: Hey Jake, this really isn't an answer, you haven't explained why he's code is not working, did you? Your answer is a quick way on how to get a lot of downvotes.

Comment: Default `type` of `<input>` is already "text" if none is provided

Comment: @LazarMomcilovic Appreciate the candor I didn't realize. I'll expand on the answer as soon as I can.

charlietfl Good info! Just confirmed in the docs you're totally right. I'll remove that recommendation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Sorry did not realize I had the class property twice in there but your solution did not work